# How to remove or ignore values from certain nesting level with jq

Tags: json, nested, jq, ellipsis

I have a deeply nested JSON, which is too large to look through; I want to remove all items from a certain level of nesting, preferably with `jq`.

Say, the JSON is:

```
{
  "paging": {
    "next": "items?page=12",
    "previous": "items?page=10"
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10200,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "id": 1337,
        "really large struct 1": "with long and complexed nested values"
      },
      {
        "id": 1338,
        "really large struct 1": "with long and complexed nested values"
      }
    ]
  },
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false
}
```

In this example, I want to omit everything under `.hits.hits`, maybe replace it with an ellipsis (…) or simply ignore it. A good alternative would be to render only the `id` value in the example.

The fields like `paging`, `took`, and `timed_oud` are examples and could change, or be a rather long and wieldy list, so simply allowlisting (whitelisting) all stuff that should stay is not an option: I want to filter out a certain depth and not show that; filtering on certain denylisted (blacklisted) items like removing all `.hits.hits.*` is OK, though.

I've tried `jq '.' | cut -c1-40` and that removes the need for horizontal scrolling and/or wrapping, but not the long vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update all members of `.hits.hits` to leave only the `id` field using the program below, I guess this is what you're looking for.

```
.hits.hits[] |= {id}
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vilCNy-iTD)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> I want to remove all items from a certain level of nesting

Here's a function that does so for any given level, $n:

```
def maxdepth($n):
  . as $in
  | reduce paths as $p (null;
       if ($p|length) > $n
       then .
       else ($in | getpath($p) ) as $v
       | if ($p|length) == $n
         then if (($v|type =="object") and ($v|length>1))
              then setpath($p; "{...}" )
              elif (($v|type == "array") and ($v|length>1))
              then setpath($p; "[...]" )
              else setpath($p; $v) 
              end
         else setpath($p; $v) 
         end
       end) ;
```

#### maxdepth(2)

Using your example, `maxdepth(2)` produces:

```
{
  "paging": {
    "next": "items?page=12",
    "previous": "items?page=10"
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10200,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": "[...]"
  },
  "took": 11,
  "timed_out": false
}
```

Comment: I didn't know jq could handle scripts and functions. Could you add a note on how to use this function with `jq`, or must this be  ran with a (perl?) interpreter outside of jq?

Comment: Please see the section”Defining Functions” in the jq manual, e.g. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/